# Drag and Drop feature with Dropzone and want to include editable text field

Tags: jquery, drag-and-drop, dropzone.js

I was trying to make a drag and drag feature using dropzone.js, but facing some difficulties while making it.

Please ref the image. [image]

1). After dragging the image in drag area, image should upload just below that section, not in that section, I was able to upload image on same drag and drop area but don't know how to move it down.

2). There should be a editable text area box along with image, try to find it but didn't get any.

Please help me, what to do to make same as ref. image.

Thanks all in advance

Answer (score 0):

```
this.on("success", function (file, responseText) {
                    //$('div.dz-file-preview').remove();
                    if ($("#demo-upload .dz-preview").length > 0)
                    {
                        $("#demo-upload .dz-preview").append('<input type="text">');
                    }

                });

On your success event add this
```